# \cline doesn't work

Tags: tables, rules

I'd like to draw a partial horizontal line just below of 'first second third' row, but `\cline` doesn't work. Any suggestion?

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor,multirow}

\begin{document}
%%%
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{table example}
  \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \rowcolors[]{2}{blue!20}{blue!10}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|cccccc|} \hline
      \rowcolor[gray]{.9}
      &
      \multicolumn{2}{>{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}c}{first} &
      \multicolumn{2}{>{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}c}{second} &
      \multicolumn{2}{>{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}c|}{third} \\
      \cline{2-7}
      \rowcolor[gray]{.9}
      \multirow{-2}{*}{left}
      & $x_1$ & $x_2$ & $x_3$ & $x_4$ & $x_5$ & $x_6$ \\ \hline
      A & a1 & a2 & a3 & a4 & a5 & a6 \\ 
      B & b1 & b2 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\columncolor{blue!20}}c}{b34} & b5 & b6 \\
      C & c1 & c2 & c3 & c4 & c5 & c6 \\
      D & d1 & d2 & d3 & d4 & d5 & d6 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). The `\cline` is working fine. However you are also coloring the rows and hence it does not show up. If you comment out the `\rowcolor` commands you'll see that it is working.  Are you sure you want to use `rowcolor` **and** a `\cline` to separate rows? Seems like only one should be necessary to do the job.

Comment: @Herbert Thanks for removing the {beamer} tag -- I hadn't been sure if `beamer` was relevant to this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the `\cline` is working but is hidden due to the coloring of the rows, and it seems to me to be a bit of an overkill to use both a horizontal rule along with coloring to separate a row.

1. My suggestion would be to remove the row color in the second row, and use `\cellcolor` to ensure that the `\multirow` text is properly colored:

   [image]
2. Another option is to use `\cmidrule` from the `booktabs` package (see *Known Issues* below). 
   This package highly recommends that you **not** use vertical lines in tables, but have left them in as that was in the original MWE.  Note that this also requires setting

   `\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}` and
      `\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}`

   [image]
3. Use [the `\hhline` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline) which provides a command similar to `\hline` which takes a parameter similar to a `tabular` specification, so that vertical lines can be properly handled.  The output of this is similar to that produced in #2 above. (see *Known Issues* below)

### Known Issues

- Both the `booktabs` and `hhline` solutions have an issue in that there is a white line in the `\multirow` text which I do not know how to fix.

### Code: Remove row color from second row:

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor,multirow}

\begin{document}
%%%
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{table example}
  \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \rowcolors[]{2}{blue!20}{blue!10}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|cccccc|} \hline
      \rowcolor[gray]{.9}
      &
      \multicolumn{2}{>{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}c}{first} &
      \multicolumn{2}{>{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}c}{second} &
      \multicolumn{2}{>{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}c|}{third} \\
      \cline{2-7}
      \rowcolor[gray]{1}
      \multirow{-2}{*}{left\cellcolor[gray]{.9}}
      & $x_1$ & $x_2$ & $x_3$ & $x_4$ & $x_5$ & $x_6$ \\ \hline
      A & a1 & a2 & a3 & a4 & a5 & a6 \\ 
      B & b1 & b2 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\columncolor{blue!20}}c}{b34} & b5 & b6 \\
      C & c1 & c2 & c3 & c4 & c5 & c6 \\
      D & d1 & d2 & d3 & d4 & d5 & d6 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Code: Use `booktabs` package:

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor,multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}

\begin{document}
%%%
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{table example}
  \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \rowcolors[]{2}{blue!20}{blue!10}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|cccccc|} \hline
      \rowcolor[gray]{.9}
      &
      \multicolumn{2}{>{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}c}{first} &
      \multicolumn{2}{>{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}c}{second} &
      \multicolumn{2}{>{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}c|}{third} \\
      \cmidrule{2-7}
      \rowcolor[gray]{.9}
      \multirow{-2}{*}{left}
      & $x_1$ & $x_2$ & $x_3$ & $x_4$ & $x_5$ & $x_6$ \\ \hline
      A & a1 & a2 & a3 & a4 & a5 & a6 \\ 
      B & b1 & b2 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\columncolor{blue!20}}c}{b34} & b5 & b6 \\
      C & c1 & c2 & c3 & c4 & c5 & c6 \\
      D & d1 & d2 & d3 & d4 & d5 & d6 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Code: `hhline` package:

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor,multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}
%%%
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{table example}
  \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \rowcolors[]{2}{blue!20}{blue!10}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|cccccc|} \hline
      \rowcolor[gray]{.9}
      &
      \multicolumn{2}{>{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}c}{first} &
      \multicolumn{2}{>{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}c}{second} &
      \multicolumn{2}{>{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}c|}{third} \\
      %\cline{2-7}
      \hhline{~|------}
      \rowcolor[gray]{.9}
      \multirow{-2}{*}{left}
      & $x_1$ & $x_2$ & $x_3$ & $x_4$ & $x_5$ & $x_6$ \\ \hline
      A & a1 & a2 & a3 & a4 & a5 & a6 \\ 
      B & b1 & b2 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\columncolor{blue!20}}c}{b34} & b5 & b6 \\
      C & c1 & c2 & c3 & c4 & c5 & c6 \\
      D & d1 & d2 & d3 & d4 & d5 & d6 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

that is only a problem with the pdf viewer. Here is your example without any change:

[image]

Increasing or decreasing the zoom gives a "hidden" line. You must controll the behaviour with your viewer in the full-screen mode. And if the line is present can also be tested with a printed output which should show all lines.

Comment: I tried with Acrobat 10.1 on Mac and it does **not** display the horizontal line, but surprisingly Mac Preview **does** show it!!  However, Section 10 of [the `colortbl` documentation](http://ctan.org/pkg/colortbl) seems to indicate that a _feature_ of `\cline` is that "they are covered up by any colour pannels in the following row".

Answer (score 3):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you will have the expected result. The rules won't seem to disappear and you won't see thin white lines, whatever PDF viewer you use.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{|c|cccccc|}
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor[gray]{0.9}{1,2}
  \rowcolors{3}{blue!20}{blue!10}
\Body
\Hline
  \Block{2-1}{left} & \Block{1-2}{first} & & \Block{1-2}{second} & & \Block{1-2}{third} \\
\Hline
    & $x_1$ & $x_2$ & $x_3$ & $x_4$      & $x_5$ & $x_6$ \\
\Hline
  A & a1    & a2    & a3    & a4         & a5   & a6 \\
  B & b1    & b2    & \Block{1-2}{b34} & & b5   & b6 \\
  C & c1    & c2    & c3    & c4         & c5   & c6 \\
  D & d1    & d2    & d3    & d4         & d5   & d6 \\
\Hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The command `\Hline` provided by `nicematrix` draws horizontal rules, excepted in the blocks. That's why, in this example, there is no need to use `\cline` (but it's also possible to use it with the same output).

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]