# \cline is in tables too thin (when using coloured cells)

Tags: tables, color

I'm having an issue where `\cline` appears to be drawn under the fill for table colours.

#### With `\hline`

[image]

#### With `\cline`

(to remove the line above the cell I want blank)

[image]

The line is still there, only very very thin. This doesn't always display or print. Is there anything simple I can do to fix this?

Here's the source for my example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

%odd/eaven colours for tables
\rowcolors{2}{gray!10}{white}

%to change cells of the title row 
\newcommand{\titlecol}{\cellcolor{gray!30}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l| c c | c c |}
\cline{2-5}
%\hline
\rowcolor{white} %first cell is excluded from the table
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\titlecol Title1} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\titlecol Title2} \\
\hline
A & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
B & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
C & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
D & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption.}
\label{mytable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What happens if you type `\ \cline{2-5}`?

Comment: @CommuSoft I get an error: `Misplaced \omit. \@cline #1-#2\@nil ->\omit`

Comment: please read the colortbl documentation. cline is explicitly not supported. Use hhline instead.

Answer (score 5):

#### Thanks all for your answers and comments!

There's also this, now I know what to search for: [Colored tables and cline/hhline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101249/colored-tables-and-cline-hhline)

This is what I ended up with (using `\hhline{~|--|--|}`):

[image]

I've only looked briefly, but it looks like this is what the characters in hline do:

- `~` no line for one cell
- `|` the corner between horizontal and vertical lines, although I'm not sure if I needed the middle one
- `-` the line for a cell

[See the docs](http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}

%odd/eaven colours for tables
\rowcolors{2}{gray!10}{white}

\newcommand{\titlecol}{\cellcolor{gray!30}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l| c c | c c |}
\hhline{~|*4{-}|}
%\cline{2-5}
%\hline
\rowcolor{white}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\titlecol Title1} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\titlecol Title2} \\
\hline
A & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
B & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
C & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
D & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption.}
\label{mytable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found out the following: the line is not too thin, it is simply overwritten by the filled cells. Some pdf readers notice the small difference in y-value and paint the line, others don't.

A similar question has been asked here:

[\cline doesn't work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39761/cline-doesnt-work)

I propose you solve this problem with one of the proposed methods as listed in the extended answer on this question.

Answer (score 0):

For information, here is (easy) way to construct that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

In that environment, there is a key `corners` to compute the empty corners of the tabular (here the corner in the north-west`). Then the rules, are not drawn in the corners and the instructions of color don't color the cells in the corners.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{|l|cc|cc|}[color-inside,corners=NW] % NW : north-west
\Hline
\rowcolor{gray!30}
& \Block{1-2}{Title1} && \Block{1-2}{Title2} \\
\Hline
\rowcolors{gray!10}{}
A & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
B & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
C & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
D & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\Hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Caption.}
\label{mytable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/TikZ nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]