# Table: the border disappers when setting the cell color

Tags: tables, border, zooming

I referenced the code from https://www.tablesgenerator.com/ and set the cell color. But I found the cell border disappeared in generated table.

[image]
[image]

code:

```
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{multirow}
% \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
% If you use beamer only pass "xcolor=table" option, i.e. \documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|ccc|c|c|c|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Package}                                                             & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}                       & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}                                   & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}                                  \\ \cline{1-3}
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}QFP100} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}QFP64} & QFP48 & \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Name} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Digital Function} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Analog Function} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1}                              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1}                             & 1     & A                                              & A                                                          & -                                                         \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2}                              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2}                             & 2     & B                                              & B                                                          & -                                                         \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I tried replaceing `\cline{1-3}` with `hhline{---}`, but the result was also problematic
[image]

Another problem, when zoom to 80%, more borders are no longer displayed
[image]

If the cell color is not set, there is no problem with the above
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Unrelated, but the code should be optimized: Change the column definitions from `|ccc|c|c|c|` to `|c|c|c|c|c|c|` and then remove all these `\multicolumn{1}{...}{...}` since they are not necessary. Finally, changing `\\ \cline{1-3}` to `\\[-.4pt] \hhline{---~~~}` should do the trick.

Comment: This problem has been discussed already, apart from the question linked as duplicate also e.g. in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101249/47927 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/162814/47927 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39761/47927

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE!!

I don't know your table generator (or any other, for that matter), but I think your table is easy to do with `tabularray` package. The code will be brief, simple and very legible (IMHO).

Something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}     % dummy text
\usepackage{tabularray} % clean tables
\usepackage{xcolor}     % colors

\definecolor{mygray}{HTML}{C0C0C0}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[ht]\centering
\begin{tblr}
{% format:
   colspec={cccccc},    % centered columns
   hlines,vlines,       % horizontal and vertical lines
   cell{1}{1}={c=3}{},  % enlarege cell{1}{1} to 3 columns
   cell{1}{4-6}={r=2}{},% enlarge cells {1}{4}, {1}{5} and {1}{6} to 2 rows
   row{1,2}={bg=mygray},% fisrt 2 rows with gray background
   cells={font=\sffamily}
}% content:
Package &       &       & Name & Digital Function & Analog Function\\
QFP100  & QFP64 & QFP48 &      &                  &\\
1       & 1     & 1     & A    & A                & -\\
2       & 2     & 2     & B    & B                & -
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:** same example with `longtblr` suggested by the comments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}     % dummy text
\usepackage{tabularray} % clean tables
\usepackage{xcolor}     % colors

\definecolor{mygray}{HTML}{C0C0C0}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{longtblr}
[% longtable format:
  caption=Some title.,
]
{% format:
   colspec={cccccc},
   hlines,vlines,       % horizontal and vertical lines
   cell{1}{1}={c=3}{},  % enlarege cell{1}{1} to 3 columns
   cell{1}{4-6}={r=2}{},% enlarge cells {1}{4}, {1}{5} and {1}{6} to 2 rows
   row{1,2}={bg=mygray},% fisrt 2 rows with gray backgraound
   cells={font=\sffamily},
   rowhead=2,
}% content:
Package &       &       & Name & Digital Function & Analog Function\\
QFP100  & QFP64 & QFP48 &      &                  &\\
1       & 1     & 1     & A    & A                & -\\
1       & 1     & 1     & A    & A                & -\\
1       & 1     & 1     & A    & A                & -\\
1       & 1     & 1     & A    & A                & -\\
1       & 1     & 1     & A    & A                & -\\
1       & 1     & 1     & A    & A                & -\\
2       & 2     & 2     & B    & B                & -
\end{longtblr}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Youngman, `tabularray` package provides a `longtblr` environment, similar to `longtable` but with all the advantages of `tabularray`. In other order of things, why didn't you say that in your post?

Comment: Thanks,  I'm trying ```longtblr```. The earliest post, I only wanted to explain the problem with simple code, so I didn't mention ```longtable```.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SX! The code can be simplified radically (which is not surprising, since table generators are known for the overly complicated code they produce):

- Changing the column definitions from `|ccc|c|c|c|` to `|c|c|c|c|c|c|`. allows you to remove all instances of `\multicolumn{1}{...}{...}`.
- If you use `\rowcolor`, there is no need to additionally add `\cellcolor` unless single cells should have another color, which is not the case here.
- Finally, you can use `\hhline`, but you need to adjust the spacing a bit. So, changing `\\ \cline{1-3}` to `\\[-.4pt] \hhline{---~~~}` should do the trick.

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl, xcolor, multirow, hhline}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Package} & & & \\[-.4pt] \hhline{---~~~}
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
    QFP100 & QFP64 & QFP48 & \multirow{-2}{*}{Name} & \multirow{-2}{*}{Digital Function} & \multirow{-2}{*}{Analog Function} \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1 & A & A & - \\ \hline
2 & 2 & 2 & B & B & - \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]