# Customized table with colored row

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn, rowcolor

How can I create a table like the following? 
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{comment} 
\usepackage{subfig} 
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{physics} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[super]{nth} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{color,colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin {table}[H]
\caption {Table Title} \label{tab:title}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{A} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{B} \\
\cline{2-4}
 & C & D &F\\
\hline
1 & x &  x & x \\
\hline
 2 & x &x & x\\
\hline
3 & x & x& x\\
\hline
% etc. ...
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: have you tried to create a **basic table** with the same content? At least this would be a starting point to attract further advice. At the moment it comes across as you wanting someone else to do the hard work for you :-(

Comment: Could you please show us what you have already tried in LaTeX in the from of a minimal working example (MWE)?

Comment: This one I made by Microsoft Word. But I have a similar table in latex without the coloring. I used "\usepackage[table]{xcolor}" and I got errors. I wanted to see if there is another approach than using \multicolumn and \multirow  that is compatible with the coloring of certain cells.

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger A Minimal Working Example is added 20 min ago!

Comment: @faf a MWE must be compilable --- starting from `\documentclass` and adding all the needed packages. Yours is just a snippet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar solution, other package:

```
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\begin{document}
\begin {table}[h]
\caption {Table Title} \label{tab:title}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c}
\rowcolor{Gray}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{D} \\
\hline
\addlinespace
\rowcolor{Gray}
& E & F & &\\
1 & x &  x & x \\
 2 & x &x & x\\
3 & x & x& x\\
\hline
% etc. ...
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

produces the following table.

[image]

Comment: @faf good that the above solution was useful. It will help others with similar issues if you mark the answer as accepted (by clicking on the tick) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code a bit and now it looks like this:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\begin {table}[H]
\caption {Table Title} \label{tab:title}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\toprule
\rowcolor{Gray} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{B}  &  &\\
\cline{2-3}
\rowcolor{Gray}\multirow{-2}{*}{A}&E&F&\multirow{-2}{*}{C}&\multirow{-2}{*}{D}\\
\midrule
1 & x &  x & x &x\\
\midrule
 2 & x &x & x&x\\
\midrule
3 & x & x& x&x\\
\bottomrule
% etc. ...
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I also replaced your `\hline` by `\top-/mid-/bottomrule` as it makes nicer tables. I also replaced `\begin{center}...\end{center}` through `\centering`.

Unfortunately, your `\cline` won't be visible as the color hides the line. The reason for this you can also see here in a [former asked question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39761/cline-doesnt-work).

Comment: Thanks! Which package should I use with it?

Comment: You need these packages:

`\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}`

Comment: I'm getting again this error. "option clash for package xcolor." P.S. I'm using Overleaf, but it shouldn't matter I guess.

Comment: Okay, then you are using a package, which already loads `xcolor`. Do you use `tikz`?

Comment: you get option clashes with `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` with other packages, for example `\usepackage{textgreek}`. What does the editor in Overleaf flag up?

Comment: \usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}

Comment: Okay, put your `\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}` in front of all that packages. This solved the problem when I tried. Often, the order of the packages matters.